# ActiveAndroid get data from two tables with CursorLoader (custom ContentProvider?)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager, activeandroid

In active `android` there is option to get data from database using `CursorLoader`, but in example there is only option with 1 table:

```
MyActivity.this.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle cursor) {
        return new CursorLoader(MyActivity.this,
            ContentProvider.createUri(TodoItem.class, null),
            null, null, null, null
        );
    }
    // ...
```

});

I want to make join, in normal case i would make `uri` in content provider for joined tables, but `ActiveAndroid` delivers `ContentProvider`, and i dont know how should i do it. Is there option to use custom `ContentProvider` with `ActiveAndroid`? Or is there other option?

Comment: Have you find it out yet?

Comment: ya if you have got the answers please help me out , i too want to do the same thing